# React - Ag-grid cellRendering only on one column header

Tags: ag-grid-react

I am trying to add a button to only one AG-Grid header. I am able to add buttons to all headers using frameworkComponents but I need to apply it to a specific column. I tried headerComponentFramework but couldn't succeed. Any Idea of how to achieve it in ReactJS based project. This question is similar to [Angular - Ag-grid cellRendering only on one column header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50086734/angular-ag-grid-cellrendering-only-on-one-column-header)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.You can use any custom button. I used material button for demo [Button in custom header of Ag-gird](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-header-button-for-ag-grid-huelj)

Comment: I couldn't find a button for any ag-grid header in the example

Comment: Unfortunately removed demo and now I updated. 

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-ag-grid-cellrendering-only-on-one-column-header-l59b5?file=/src/Grid.js